# update database based on select/unselect items in Multi select dropdown list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I have a multi select dropdown list implemented with angular material design
and it's working, it loads all the possible options (Categories) and it checks the items selected already.

I want to update database based on select/unselect in this dropdown list.
How can I do so?

```
<md-select ng-model="SelectedItems" multiple>
    <md-option ng-repeat="item in Categories">{{item}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just take this an example and write your update code with in  $scope.onChange function

**html**

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" layout layout-align="center center">
    <md-select ng-model="myModel" placeholder="Pick" ng-change="onChange(myModel)" >
        <md-option value="0">Zero</md-option>
        <md-option value="1">One</md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>
```

**js**

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.onChange = function(k) {
alert(k);
        //your code here for storing in db
    };


})
```

Answer (score 2):

check this [ng-change directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

It will get you the value in controller as soon as you check/uncheck (function) then call the query function to update the database. Hope it helps.